# Training FCN8s semantic segmentation on DIGITS/Caffe multi GPU

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, caffe, nvidia-digits

Has anyone had success in training a semantic segmentation model (FCN8s) using DIGITS (v5) in multi-GPU mode?

I can successfully train on a single GPU, but it's very slow.

When I select multiple GPUs (my workstation has 4 Titan Xp), the entire system shuts down and restarts. This seems to be a problem that others have reported in the nVidia DIGITS Google group.

Any insight is greatly appreciated.

Ubuntu 14.04
Caffe 0.15.13
DIGITS 5.0